# How to prevent VirtualBox VM crashing into "Aborted" when resuming it from a snapshot with running OpenGL application inside?

Tags: virtualbox, opengl, snapshot, acceleration

When I try snapshot/restore-state in VirtualBox 4.0.4, it works.

Hovewer, if I try restoring snapshot when some OpenGL-enabled application is running inside VM, VM crashes immediately after starting.

This happens even if application window is minimized and process is suspended inside VM.

How to use snapshots and 3D acceleration simultaneously? What VirtualBox version is reported to work in this mode?

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/278658/checkpointing-opengl-applications